# Submitting A Form Through Ajax And Displaying Errors

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm attempting to submit step one of my 3 page form via ajax for my Laravel application and I have it set up so that when validation fails on this submission it will submit back with the validation errors which it dos however it still proceeds to the next step in the form process. What am I doing wrong for that to happen still? I understand that I'm not doing anything when there are errors in the ajax response but why is it still doing what's in the success if there is errors. Does it check errors first then success?

```
/*
* Create User After they complete the first part of the form. 
*
*/
public function createUserFromOrder(Request $request)
{
    $validation = $this->validate($request, [
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|confirm|unique:users,email',
        'email_confirmation' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validation->fails()) {
        return Response()::json([
            'success' => false,
            'errors' => $validation->errors()->toArray()
        ], 200);
    }

    $randomPassword = str_random(7);
    $createdSuccessfully = "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'><span class='status-available'> User Profile Created.</span></div>";
    $userData = [
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $randomPassword,
        'first_name' => $request->first_name,
        'last_name' => $request->last_name,
    ];

    $user = Sentinel::registerAndActivate($userData);
    $role = Sentinel::findRoleByName('patient');
    $role->users()->attach($user);

    Sentinel::login($user, true);

    $order = Order::create([
        'program_id' => $request->program_id,
        'program_type_id' => $request->program_type_id,
        'amount' => 433,
        'order_type' => 0,
        'paid' => 0,
        'status' => 0
    ]);
    $user->complete($order);
    $order->addAddon($request->input('addons'));

    return $createdSuccessfully;
}


$.ajax({
        type: "POST",            
        url: '{{action('OrderProcessController@createUserFromOrder') }}',
        data:
            {
                email: email,
                first_name: first_name, 
                last_name: last_name,
                program_id: program_id,
                program_type_id: program_type_id,
                amount: amount,
                addons: addons
            },
        success:function(data){            
            $("#user-created-confirmation").html(data);
        },
        error:function (){}
    }, function(){
        setTimeout(function() {

        })
    });
```

Comment: Can you show your ajax code?

Comment: @Amit If you look at the bottom of the code its there.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because you may be misunderstanding the "success" property of .ajax()
It just means that the AJAX request was made successfully, and not weather your form passed validation. You should put your error handler function inside success function like this:

```
success:function(data){  
        if(AreThereErrors() == false) {
            $("#user-created-confirmation").html(data);
        } else {
            HandleErrors();
        }
    },
```

Comment: So you don't think its the 422 error code messing it up? I even did a console.log(data) inside the success method and for some reason it doesn't even hit that log. Don't know why.

Comment: should've mentioned the 422 error code :) google tells me 422 means "unprocessable entity", so i suggest you look at your "data" more closely. Try sending one variable at a time. Also, try in your .ajax()
beforeSend: function() { console.log(data); } to see what exactly you're trying to send

Answer (score 0):

If your status code is other than `200` then `error` block of ajax call is called. Try to execute your code there.

For example:

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: No matter what for some reason it still reports back as 422.

Comment: Have tried the updated answer, the `error` block code?

Comment: Yes I have and received the same response.